# Access Denied Error Symfony with roles without prefix 'ROLE_'

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

Good morning, I want to update my symfony 2.8 application to version 5.4.
I am having problems with the is_granted function of symfony.

My connected user has all the roles in the token (classic roles + custom roles). Custom roles are linked to the company and each user of a company inherits the roles of the company.

I add all the roles in the token however when I put an is_granted on a rest class, I get an access denied. Could you tell me if I forgot something please?

My REST class with the is_granted function :

```
/**
 * TrainingSession controller.
 * @RouteResource("Training")
 * @Security("is_granted('MODULE_TRAINING')")
 */
class TrainingSessionRESTController extends BaseRESTController
{
```

My token with the corresponding role :

```
  "ROLE_HR"
  "ROLE_DEBUG"
  "ROLE_PANEL"
  "ROLE_USER"
  "ROLE_MANAGER"
  "MODULE_LIBRARY"
  "MODULE_EXPENSE_REPORT"
  "MODULE_TRAINING"
  "MODULE_ANNUAL_REVIEW"
  "MODULE_PRO_REVIEW"
  "MODULE_COMPANY_CHART"
  "MODULE_COMPANY_CONTACT"
  "MODULE_COMPANY_DOCUMENT"
  "MODULE_CALENDAR"
  "MODULE_FOLDER"
  "MODULE_TIME_MANAGEMENT"
  "MODULE_EMPLOYEE_MEDICAL"
  "MODULE_REPORT"
```

I tried to override the class which adds the "ROLE_" prefix. This is the RoleVoter class but without success, the prefix still seems to be taken into account.

This is my custom RoleVoter and I tried to set the prefix to empty but without success :

```
namespace WORD\CoreBundle\Voter;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

/**
 * RoleVoter votes if any attribute starts with a given prefix.
 *
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 */
class CustomVoter implements CacheableVoterInterface
{
    private $prefix;

    public function __construct(string $prefix = 'ROLE_')
    {
        $this->prefix = 'ROLE_';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $subject, array $attributes)
    {
        
        $result = VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
        $roles = $this->extractRoles($token);

        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if (!\is_string($attribute) || !str_starts_with($attribute, $this->prefix)) {
                continue;
            }

            if ('ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN' === $attribute) {
                trigger_deprecation('symfony/security-core', '5.1', 'The ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN role is deprecated and will be removed in version 6.0, use the IS_IMPERSONATOR attribute instead.');
            }

            $result = VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                if ($attribute === $role) {
                    return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function supportsAttribute(string $attribute): bool
    {
        return str_starts_with($attribute, $this->prefix);
    }

    public function supportsType(string $subjectType): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected function extractRoles(TokenInterface $token)
    {
        return $token->getRoleNames();
    }
}
```

I can't rename all my roles by adding the prefix 'ROLE_' because my roles are specified in the front

Comment: Not sure when this changed (S4 I think) but [somewhat sadly](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#roles): `The only rule is that every role must start with the ROLE_ prefix - otherwise, things won't work as expected. `  Looks like you have a bit of refactoring to do.  I know you said you can't add the prefix for some reason but short of trying to tweak the internal authorization code, I don't think you have much choice.

Comment: Hello @Cerad, I also notice that in the documentation of version 2.8 we had the same recommendation. However, my roles were still taken into account. https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security.html#roles

Comment: I kind of think that was before the deprecation system was implemented.  So the docs would warn not to do something but the functionality was still there until the next major release.  The description `work as expected` is pretty vague.  I'd have to go through the isGranted code just to see what changed.  But that sort of code is not pretty.  I could imagine adjusting User::getRoles to add the prefix but the rest of the system?  Yikes.

Comment: I agree, the description is actually quite vague.
I found the place where we do the prefix check. It's in the RoleVoter class. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/Voter/RoleVoter.php[link].  I tried to override this class to set the $prefix to '' but without success

Answer (score 1):

this is my configuration and works for me:

```
security.access.simple_role_voter:
    public: true
    class: Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\RoleVoter
    arguments: [ '' ]
```

in this way i don't have any restriction for role prefixes.

i'm in 5.4 version